# How to generate sequence on a file with millions records (daily incremental load) in Spark2

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a business scenario to generate surrogate key on daily incremental table or file in spark 2.0 with scala 2.11.8. I know about "zipwithindex", "row_num" and "monotonically_increasing_id()" but none of them works for daily incremental load, as for today's load my sequence would be 1 + yesterday's sequence.
Accumulator's also won't work as it is write only.

Ex. Scenario: Till yesterday's load I have last customer_sk as 1001, now in today's load I want to set customer_sk that will starts from 1002 till end of file.

Note: I will have millions of rows , the program will be running on multiple nodes in parallel.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Get max `customer_sk` from the table.

2) then when using `row_num` add this max `customer_sk` number so that your sequence continue from that.

If using `rdd` also, add the previous max number to the `(zipwithindex +1)`.

Comment: Thanks Praveen, It worked although I tried it in local mode with few records yet to test on main cluster in distributed environment.

Answer (score 0):

For all those who are still looking for answer with sample code.

```
hdfs dfs -cat /user/shahabhi/test_file_2.csv
```

abhishek,shah,123,pune,2018-12-31,2018-11-30
abhishek,shah,123,pune,2018-12-31,2018-11-30
ravi,sharma,464,mumbai,20181231,20181130
Mitesh,shah,987,satara,2018-12-31,2018-11-30
shalabh,nagar,981,satara,2018-12-31,2018-11-30
Gaurav,mehta,235,ujjain,2018/12/31,2018/11/30
Gaurav,mehta,235,ujjain,2018-12-31,2018-11-30
vikas,khanna,123,ujjain,2018-12-31,2018-11-30
vinayak,kale,789,pune,2018-12-31,2018-11-30

Spark code--

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id

val df =spark.read.csv("/user/shahabhi/test_file_2.csv").toDF("name","lname","d_code","city","esd","eed")

df.show()
```

+--------+------+------+------+----------+----------+
|    name| lname|d_code|  city|       esd|       eed|
+--------+------+------+------+----------+----------+
|abhishek|  shah|   123|  pune|2018-12-31|2018-11-30|
|abhishek|  shah|   123|  pune|2018-12-31|2018-11-30|
|    ravi|sharma|   464|mumbai|  20181231|  20181130|
|  Mitesh|  shah|   987|satara|2018-12-31|2018-11-30|
| shalabh| nagar|   981|satara|2018-12-31|2018-11-30|
|  Gaurav| mehta|   235|ujjain|2018/12/31|2018/11/30|
|  Gaurav| mehta|   235|ujjain|2018-12-31|2018-11-30|
|   vikas|khanna|   123|ujjain|2018-12-31|2018-11-30|
| vinayak|  kale|   789|  pune|2018-12-31|2018-11-30|
+--------+------+------+------+----------+----------+

```
val df_2=df.withColumn("surrogate_key", monotonically_increasing_id())

df_2.show()
```

+--------+------+------+------+----------+----------+-------------+
|    name| lname|d_code|  city|       esd|       eed|surrogate_key|
+--------+------+------+------+----------+----------+-------------+
|abhishek|  shah|   123|  pune|2018-12-31|2018-11-30|            0|
|abhishek|  shah|   123|  pune|2018-12-31|2018-11-30|            1|
|    ravi|sharma|   464|mumbai|  20181231|  20181130|            2|
|  Mitesh|  shah|   987|satara|2018-12-31|2018-11-30|            3|
| shalabh| nagar|   981|satara|2018-12-31|2018-11-30|            4|
|  Gaurav| mehta|   235|ujjain|2018/12/31|2018/11/30|            5|
|  Gaurav| mehta|   235|ujjain|2018-12-31|2018-11-30|            6|
|   vikas|khanna|   123|ujjain|2018-12-31|2018-11-30|            7|
| vinayak|  kale|   789|  pune|2018-12-31|2018-11-30|            8|
+--------+------+------+------+----------+----------+-------------+

```
val df_3=df.withColumn("surrogate_key", monotonically_increasing_id()+1000)
df_3.show()
```

+--------+------+------+------+----------+----------+-------------+
|    name| lname|d_code|  city|       esd|       eed|surrogate_key|
+--------+------+------+------+----------+----------+-------------+
|abhishek|  shah|   123|  pune|2018-12-31|2018-11-30|         1000|
|abhishek|  shah|   123|  pune|2018-12-31|2018-11-30|         1001|
|    ravi|sharma|   464|mumbai|  20181231|  20181130|         1002|
|  Mitesh|  shah|   987|satara|2018-12-31|2018-11-30|         1003|
| shalabh| nagar|   981|satara|2018-12-31|2018-11-30|         1004|
|  Gaurav| mehta|   235|ujjain|2018/12/31|2018/11/30|         1005|
|  Gaurav| mehta|   235|ujjain|2018-12-31|2018-11-30|         1006|
|   vikas|khanna|   123|ujjain|2018-12-31|2018-11-30|         1007|
| vinayak|  kale|   789|  pune|2018-12-31|2018-11-30|         1008|
+--------+------+------+------+----------+----------+-------------+

Comment: I would go with this option although the platforms are pretty powerful these days.